# php use of decimal exponent

Tags: php, decimal, exponent

I am working in php and using mathcad to formulate an equation. My equation requires a number raised to an irrational exponent in which the exponent iterates as a decimal. The exponent includes a variable array and other decimals that end up as a decimal through each array iteration. I can't get the equation to output.

I am using

```
$delta_graph = .1;$var1 = .497;# $s = if lower: shift right and higher.   
$var2 = 109.94;# $e = if lower: right and left are higher at diff. rates.
$var3 = 3.615;# $m = if higher: shift left and lower and flatten left.
$data = array();
for ($x = 0; $x <= 120; $x+= $delta_graph)# $x + n = if higher: curve shifts left and higher.
  $data[] = array('', $x, $Sbs_now2 + ((19050.6/$x*$var1*sqrt(2*M_PI))*(pow($var2,-.5*pow(log($x+3.6)-$var3,2))/2*pow($s,2))-0.041));
# first constant: if higher: peak is higher  final constant: if higher: curve is lower
```

, where $x is the variable array that iterates decimals. The exponent of the first pow is the decimal. The second pow obviously has 2 as its exponent. Is a decimal allowed to be an exponent, is there something I am missing, and if not, is there a hack?

My research, here and on the internet, indicates that a whole number is possibly what is required but I have not found a definite answer.

My full coding has been well tested.

Thank you All,

Gary

Comment: Can you give a better example in terms of what values `$var2`, `$x` and `$var3` take? Also it would be nice if those had names that made sense. You can't `log` an array. A **minimal** example that shows how this code is used would be great, so if you could edit your question and add that code it would help a lot.

Comment: Hi tadman, I will edit the original post. Gary

Comment: define the `$Sbs_now2` and `$s` vars inside the `for` loop. If you replace those with numbers then the result may be much prettier.

Comment: also in first iteration it get "Division by zero" with $x = 0

Comment: I got it thanks to Deadooshka and tadman. I missed the $s variable definition. It is sometimes difficult to see a small problem like this when one is buried in the larger coding. Good eye! So... php does accept decimal exponents. Thank you Deadooshka, tadman, and All. Gary